# Local Storage function always storing radio button value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, local-storage

My local storage function always stores the radio button value of "3" in local storage regardless of the selection made and I don't have an idea as of why. Every other element stores properly.

Please see my fiddle to show my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/148/

My function:

```
$('input, select, textarea').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var name = $(this).attr('name');

    if ($(this).hasClass('checkers')) {
        value = $(this).is(":checked");
        if (value) {
            value = 'on';
        } else {
            value = 'off';
        }
    }

    if (this.name.match(/^multiselect_/)) {//removes buggy append
        return false;
    }

    console.log('Saving');
    console.log(name + ':' + value);
    Survey[name] = value;
});

if (localStorage.getObj('Surveys') !== null) {
    Surveys = localStorage.getObj('Surveys');
}

Surveys[$('#FirstName').val() + '.' + $('#LastName').val()] = Survey; //store in big list
localStorage.setObj('Surveys', Surveys);
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes either; it's a fine question with code, and it's got a fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

The radio buttons all have the same name, because they're radio buttons, and they all have a value. Your code gets the value of each of the radio buttons and saves each value into the same property of the "Survey" object. The last one it sees is the one that ultimately is saved.

You'll have to add code something like you've got for checkboxes:

```
if (!$(this).is(':radio') || this.checked)
  Survey[name] = value;
```

Comment: Any easy work around to have it work with what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

As Pointy mentioned without giving any answer, you're iterating on "input, select, textarea" elements. So, after hitting on every one of your radio buttons, the third and last one of them is stored.

Admitting you put your inputs in a `<form>` tag, in pure Javascript, what you're trying to do is something like :

```
var items = document.forms;
for(var i in items){
    console.log(items[i].value);
}
```

This will show you the value for every input in your `<form>` element, iterating using their name.

(Don't know how to do this with jQuery)